# Upload images from comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, image-upload

I know images can't be displayed to comments. However, sometimes we need to [send an image in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318767/how-should-i-do-lowering-the-minimum-sdk-version/47319339#comment81610321_47319339). Right now we have to open the Ask Question page, upload the image, copy the link, /* remove the auto-inserted text if we don't want it to be saved */, and go back to the comment. Unless I use external sites to upload the image, which I shouldn't. This is a bit useless.

There should be an "Upload image" link below the "Help" link. After I upload my image, just like from the question editor, the site should insert only its link to the comment.

Comment: I believe, Just adding image urls should be enough for comments.

Comment: @mega6382 That's exactly what I said.

Comment: No, I am saying there is no need for any upload system in comments. Just upload image somewhere and share the url in the comment.

Comment: I'm not seeing why you should upload the image by creating a new question. You can just create an answer on the same page, no extra clicks, and usually even no scrolling required.

Comment: I don't believe we'd gain anything by making inserting images in comments easier. It's not something that we need to encourage.

Comment: You say you don't want to use an external site to upload to, but imgur is actually an external site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @yivi says in their comment:

> I don't believe we'd gain anything by making inserting images in comments easier. It's not something that we need to encourage.

If this were a feature that is likely to improve the quality of the content that gets posted, it's fair to ask that the process be made as smooth as possible.

It isn't, though. Images in comments *very* rarely serve a constructive purpose (and I say that as someone who unapologetically posts loads of pics in comments).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3b0g9

Comment: @Don'tPanic https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgoNN.jpg